# Instagram API /tags/tag-name/media/recent min_id not working

Tags: instagram

Code that has been working unchanged for literally 2 years has stopped working today.  It seems the /tags/tag-name/media/recent query is ignoring the min_id.

Request with and without the min_id are returning the same data.
Test for yourself: http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/

Comment: I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Same here using min_tag_id

Comment: Here is more info on the weird behavior when using min_tag_id (or min_id)  It appears that now that the min_tag_id gets stuck on a set value  it pulls in all posts after that id.  So technically it's still pulling in posts as it's supposed to, it's just not updating the min_tag_id to a higher id.  With the ID i have, it's now pulling in like 25+ posts and this keeps going up as new posts are found.  even though normally there is a 20 post cap.

Comment: As a workaround, I am iterating backwards with max_tag_id.  Since I am caching them in a database I am simply comparing each of the post id's until I get a match.  If a match is not found in the first 20, I make another call to grab the next 20 (older) posts and loop that till a match is made.

Comment: I'm resorting to something similar, but still not sure why the sudden change in the API behavior

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed just now

Comment: Yes it does seem to be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram has fixed the issue.  API is back to normal